Problema con código usando hardhat en una conexión localhost
Estoy tratando de hacer un hola mundo para aprender a utilizar hardhat y ethers.js.
Pero tengo un problema con deploy.js, cada ves que lo ejecuto me aparece la siguiente respuesta en el log --> "undefined"
Estuve buscando información e incluso ayudandome de alguna IA para ver que podría estar sucediendo pero no me ha funcionado. Les coloco lo que tengo para darme a entender mejor.
Esto es el contrato, es un simple hola mundo
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract HolaMundo {
    string public mensaje;

    constructor() {
        mensaje = "Hola Mundo";
    }

    function obtenerMensaje() public view returns (string memory) {
        return mensaje;
    }
}

Y este es el deploy.js
async function main() {
  const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
  
  // Conectar a la red local
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545");

  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

  const HolaMundo = await ethers.getContractFactory("HolaMundo");
  const holaMundo = await HolaMundo.deploy();

  console.log("HolaMundo deployed to:", holaMundo.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
  });

Y este es la configuración de hardhat
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.24",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      gasPrice: 20000000000
    }
  }
};

Buscando aqui en el foro, encontré algunas respuestas como:
Usar la version 5 de ethers 
usar npx hardhat node --hostname 127.0.0.1
quitar o comentar en hosts ::1
en la configuración de hardhat usar 127.0.0.1 en vez de localhost
usar: new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL) o new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL)
He usado varios tipos de código pero tampoco 
El resultado que siempre me da es el siguiente:
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
Deploying contracts with the account: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
HolaMundo deployed to: undefined


Y no logro avanzar de ahí, ¿alguien sabe que podría hacer?, no me importa si es con la version 5 o la más reciente, solo me interesa que funcione.
Tambien no se si sirva decir que uso linux, por si tiene algo que ver selinux o no, también en un momento de desesperación desactive el firewall pero nada, solo como dato extra.

pareciera que hace falta configurar algo ...
